# Trigger REST API immediately (real time) whenever SQL Server database table updated with expected criteria

Tags: sql-server, api, triggers, real-time, jobs

I'm looking for the right way to trigger REST API  (for sending email, it was created as an API) whenever there's a SQL Server table content updated and hitting certain conditions (e.g. value is greater than 5).

It has to be immediate instead of create a job with interval etc (or job works like real time is acceptable).

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a SQL Server Agent job written in Powershell, and a trigger that queues up the new content and calls `sp_start_job`

Comment: But it's not real time right? It is having an interval which tried to reach the table even if no content update, its waste.

Comment: Pretty real-time, how much more real-time can you get? It will fire off the job as soon as there is any update to the table. `It is having an interval which tried to reach the table even if no content update` I don't understand that, sorry.

Comment: ahh I think I misunderstand your advise. Yes I mean a trigger works, but what should the trigger do, as in calling the REST API?

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be calling out to the network from a trigger. It should just fire off a job that will do that, preferably Powershell or cmdexec (a cmd batch), do not use T-SQL for this. You are going to have to write quite a bit of code, I'm afraid this is far out of scope for a [so] question. If you are stuck on a *specific* issue, then do go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: Using API's from a trigger has been discussed many times - as has the consuming of APIs in tsql generally. Use CLR to access an API if you need to - but using a trigger to do so is a level of complication you should avoid.